# Create or parse java and kotlin clases into gradle task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I has some config class written on java. This config contains some colors field. And i want read this fields in compile time and generate style.xml based on these fields. 
This config file located on src/main/java. How i can create instance this class(config)or parse .java file during custom gradle task executed?

Comment: I would define the colors separately (e.g., in a properties file). Then use Gradle to inject them into Java via `buildConfigField`, plus write a Gradle task that generates your XML. Or, create a Gradle plugin that takes the data and generates the Java and XML (see [this project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.8/Gradle/Staticizer) for an example Gradle plugin that reads JSON and generates a `BuildConfig`-style Java class).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want single point for app configuration in these config file. If it possible of course.

Comment: "but i want single point for app configuration in these config file" -- my point is that it will be *much* easier if that single point for app configuration is in XML, JSON, `.properties`, or similar files. Generating style XML is not that difficult, and generating Java or Kotlin using JavaPoet and KotlinPoet is only somewhat more difficult. All of those are *much* easier than writing a Java or Kotlin parser.

Comment: You right. Create config and styles from JSON is next step. If it's will be very difficult im juts hardcode colors =)

Answer (score 0):

you  can use [PSI library](https://jitinsharma.in/posts/parsing-kotlin-using-code-kotlin/) if you  are working with kotlin and intellij